# Hide dropdown box generated by salesforce lookup (user) field

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, css

I created a custom lookup (user) field and then added it to my Visualforce page

```
<tr><td style="text-align:center;"><b>Engineer Assigned</b> </td></tr>
         <tr><td><apex:inputField value="{!objRD.Assigned_To__c}" rendered="{!IsEdit}"/></td></tr><br/>
         <tr><td><apex:outputField value="{!objRD.Assigned_To__c}" rendered="{!!IsEdit}"/></td></tr><br/>
```

the output looks like this:
[image]

However, I don't want the drop down box to be displayed.

Looking at the generated HTML, the ID is different for multiple instances.

```
<select name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id12_mlktp" title="Search scope" id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id12_mlktp" onchange="LookupAutoCompleteInputElement.handleLookupTypeChange('j_id0:j_id2:j_id12',false);">
```

or

```
<select name="j_id0:j_id21:j_id31_mlktp" title="Search scope" id="j_id0:j_id21:j_id31_mlktp" onchange="LookupAutoCompleteInputElement.handleLookupTypeChange('j_id0:j_id21:j_id31',false);"><option selected="selected" value="005">User</option>
```

Is there a way either using CSS or Javascript to hide all of the controls that end with _mlktp.

Any other option is greatly appreciated.

//What I have tried so far: 
1. Add a style tag to visual force and set it to hide
2. Look online for options, and will continue until I find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find the solution on this site: 
http://www.thephani.com/hide-user-dropdown-on-lookup-visualforce/

The trick in here is to hide the select generated by html altogether. This is done by css by setting the inputfield's select visibility as hidden.

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="hideDropdown" value="{!Account.OwnerId}"/>

<style>  
    .hideDropdown select{
        visibility: hidden !important;
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This was very helpful. However, the form put the input field on the next row down instead of right next to the label. I wanted the field to be right next to the label. So, I changed "display: block" to "display: none". That might be of some help to others looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved by using the `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` in conjunction with your `<apex:inputField>` and a new `<apex:outputLabel>`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand your answer. Could you please try to describe it in a different way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(){
  j$("[id$=mlktp]").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can just add `html-hidden="hidden"` to the tag and it will work.

If not you can also use:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!inputValue}" id="theHiddenInput"/>
```